# Haproxy fails to start

Tags: haproxy

I am running Ubuntu 18.04
My config files and other info are below. I installed using apt-get.

```
log /dev/log local0
log /dev/log local1 notice
chroot /var/lib/haproxy
stats timeout 30s
user haproxy
group haproxy
daemon

defaults
log global
mode http
option httplog
option dontlognull
timeout connect 5000
timeout client 50000
timeout server 50000

frontend http_front
bind *:80
stats uri /haproxy?stats
default_backend http_back

backend http_back
balance roundrobin
server server1 ip:port check
server server2 ip:port check
```

I typed in haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -db and I received this output.

```
[ALERT] 359/031621 (6151) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:2]: unknown keyword ‘log’ out of section.
[ALERT] 359/031621 (6151) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:3]: unknown keyword ‘chroot’ out of section.
[ALERT] 359/031621 (6151) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:4]: unknown keyword ‘stats’ out of section.
[ALERT] 359/031621 (6151) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:5]: unknown keyword ‘user’ out of section.
[ALERT] 359/031621 (6151) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:6]: unknown keyword ‘group’ out of section.
[ALERT] 359/031621 (6151) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:7]: unknown keyword ‘daemon’ out of section.
[ALERT] 359/031621 (6151) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:20] : unknown keyword ‘jstats’ in ‘frontend’ section
[ALERT] 359/031621 (6151) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 359/031621 (6151) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

My Haproxy status.

```
Dec 25 02:41:58 admin systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Dec 25 02:41:58 admin systemd[1]: Stopped HAProxy Load Balancer.
Dec 25 02:41:58 admin systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 25 02:41:58 admin systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result ‘exit-code’.
Dec 25 02:41:58 admin systemd[1]: Failed to start HAProxy Load Balancer.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the errors you got out of the `haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -db` command, the issue is that you did not set the section of the configs in the first section of your file. From a quick Google search, that section should be named global.

```
global
    log /dev/log local0
    log /dev/log local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
```

And I assume you fixed the last config error

```
[ALERT] 359/031621 (6151) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:20] : unknown keyword ‘jstats’ in ‘frontend’ section
```

As the key looks to be changed to `stats` instead of `jstats`

Comment: A very silly mistake of mine, thank you for helping me. I forgot to put Global in my config file.